# Point DNS to other DNS and mantain MX record

Tags: networking, dns, protocols, hosting

I have a webiste hosted in a web hosting which is down. 
My domain was pointing to this website hosting so I changed DNS records to a new hosting because we didn't recieve any emails.

In this new hosting, I changed MX records to GSuite and email is working OK.

I need to get a backup from my webiste so when the web hosting which is down comes up, I want to point my DNS for http to that webhosting so I can access the site. After backup is done, I will revert my DNS changes back so all is resolved in my new hosting.

Is there any way I can do this at DNS level without affecting the current MX records which are working OK?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I solved by changing "A" DNS record to point to the older server DNS IP.